# If $X$ is such that $c P(X\geq c) \leq E(Y; X\geq c)$ for every $c$ then so is $X\wedge n$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I came across the following as I was reading the book *Probability with Martingales* by Williams (pg 143):

> Assumption: $X$ and $Y$ are non-negative random variables such that
>   $$c P(X\geq c) \leq E(Y; X\geq c) \text{ for every } c > 0$$

Williams makes a remark that this assumption remains true for $X \wedge n$ where $\wedge$ denotes the minimum and $n$ is a positive integer.

But, I do not see why the remark is true since all I can see is that

$$ c P(X \wedge n \geq c) \leq c P(X\geq c) $$

and

$$E(Y; X\wedge n \geq c) \leq  E(Y; X\geq c)$$

So, how do I know that

$$c P(X \wedge n \geq c) \leq E(Y; X \wedge n \geq c) \text{ for every } c > 0\ ?$$

Comment: **Hint:** Consider the two cases $c\leq n$ and $c>n$ separately.

Comment: In particular, your first observation can be made quite a bit stronger for $n < c$.

Comment: @BrianTung What do you mean?  If $n<c$, then $\{ X \wedge n \geq c\} = \emptyset$, so the desired inequality holds trivially with both sides being equal to 0. Isn't it?

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Am I on the right track that the second case $c > n$ holds trivially?